# COUNTIFS and only display value the first time criteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
          A                B                C         |           D
1      Product         Quantity           Count       |       Desired Result

2      Product A         20                 2         |             2
3      Product A          0                           |
4      Product A         50                 2         |

5      Prodcut B         10                 3         |             3
6      Product B          0                           |
7      Product B         30                 3         |
8      Product B          0                           |
9      Product B         40                 3         |

10     Product C         60                 1         |             1
```

In **Column A** you can see a list of different Products and in **Column B** their quantity.

In **Column C** I want to count the products in **Column A** if the quantity in **Column B** `>0`. 
Therefore, I use the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,C1<>""),"",COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,">"&0))
```

The count itself works already with this formula. However, what I want to achieve is that the count is **only** **displayed the first time** when the product appears in the list. 
 (See desired result in **Column D**).

What do I have to change in my formula to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to wrap your existing formula in:

`IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)>1,"",[Your existing formula])`

This acts as a simple duplicate check on the first column, you can amend the `CountIf` to `CountIfs` if you intend to display the first time the quantity exceeds 0.

Please note the absolute referencing ($'s) is essential so that the formula only counts entries above itself for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at it:

```
=IF(MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$10,0)=ROW(),<your formula here>,"")
```

Add the above in `C1` and then drag it down to all rows in `C` column. Formula will automatically update the rows. `$A$10` in `MATCH`: you can either change `10` to the last row you have or have it dynamically pick up the last row.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is to create a pivot table.

(see this reference as how to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaOtCWxx3xU)

Follow these steps:

1. Use your column C with the formula:

   IF(B:B>0,1,0)
2. Then create your pivot table from this table.
3. Put "product" in ROWS and "quantity" in VALUES.
4. Then set the Value Field Settings to Amount in stead of Sum, and you're done!

The endresult will look like this:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvbTx-tJT3iRgmkPI2h--BG9_fmM (my OneDrive Excel example)

For more reference see: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576?omkt=en-GB&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB